# Are there any possible ways to use MongoDb with EF Core using AppDbContext now?

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I went through different tutorials and guides to use mongodb in .NET Core 6 and above but was searching if there be any possible ways to use mongo db with EF Core in this format.

```
var client = new MongoClient(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MongoDb"));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
options.MongoDb(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MongoDb"), "GamesDB"));

// var database = client.GetDatabase("GamesDB");
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(options =>
client);
```

As we do for `options.UseSqlServer("#getting connections")`.

Are there any alternative or easy ways to implement?

I have gone through these tutorials too: https://youtu.be/iWTdJ1IYGtg

Comment: no, there is no EF for mongo db yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB has now released an officially supported EF Core provider (currently in preview).

Github repo: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-efcore-provider

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore

Issue/bug tracker: https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/EF/issues/EF-63